# How do I remove an index or range from a QItemSelection

Tags: qt, selection

I have been unable to find anything like QItemSelection.remove() or QItemSelection.deselect(). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, the best way i have found to do this is to use a second selection with merge set to deselect:

```
deselection = QItemSelection(curr_index, curr_index)  # Can I coin deselection? ;)
selection.merge(deselection, QItemSelectionModel.Deselect)
```